# Main view is moved on returning to ViewController from next one?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, storyboard

I have a view controller with multiple UIViews on it, made in two different ways, all sitting in a scrollview. The top one was added through storyboard, and was done so to make it easier to style and work with segues. The others are more of a newsfeed post type deal, and are dynamic, so they are programmatically added. When I travel to another ViewController from this one, and I'm not scrolled all the way to the top I find that when I return, my storyboard added view is moved up, and almost out of the screen.

How do I fix this? I feel like it has something to do with the scrollView or the fact that it was added in storyboard, since the other views dont move, just this one.

Comment: What code do you have that sets up the `UIScrollView` and the `UIView` inside it? (Anything in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear:`?) Is it the `UIScrollView` or the `UIView` inside the scrollview that moves up? Are you using auto-layout? It would be helpful if you could post some code and/or a screenshot of the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I am under NDA so I cannot reveal any part of this particular story board, since it contains significant code that does what our company earns a (big) portion money off of. I am just going to delete this question and redo it entirely programmatically. Thank you for commenting though.